# jquery get method in asp.net bring me the whole html page

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I wrote a jQuery "get" method, in order to get a response from the c# code behind (of the same asp page.)

The problem is that I get the whole HTML code of the page. Instead of getting only the response value.
here is the jQuery code:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.post("AddNewBankHtml.aspx",
            function(data, status) {
                alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
           })        
        })
</script>
```

The c# code behind:

```
   public partial class AddNewBankHtml : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    [System.Web.Services.WebMethod] 
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      Response.Write(others.BanksNomber.BanksListInHtmlFormat());
    }
}
```

I googled it many times but didn't find something that helped me.
Thank you for any answer!

Comment: You tagged this as ASP.NET, but your file extension is .asp and you mentioned a code behind. Are you sure that file extension is right? And by the way, if you just want to return some data to an AJAX call, do not use a page. Use a generic handler (.ashx) or [Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api).

Comment: your question is kinda confusion. On your code behind, you have Response.Write("Hello") which just prints "hello" while you make a ajax call to a page with no method defined to where the call needs to be intercepted. What are you trying to do ?

Comment: @mason You're right. I deleted.

Comment: Hi, mason. thank you for editing.

Comment: You should use a `public static` method instead of using your `Page_Load` event...

Answer (score -1):

If you're actually using Asp.Net then your extensions should be .aspx. Since you mention using codebehind I'm assuming that's the case. So here's the way I do ajax calls using Asp.Net.

You should not use an ASPX page that has any HTML on it. The entire page only references the codebehind. Any HTML on the page will be returned along with the response text.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="AddNewBankHtml.aspx.cs" Inherits="ajax_AddNewBankHtml" %>
```

In your codebehind you need to set the response type depending on whether your outputting JSON or plain text.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Expires = -1;
    //required to keep the page from being cached on the client's browser

    Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
    Response.Write("Hello");
    Response.End();
}
```

You can output anything you like if you set correct content type: Javascript, XML, JSON, whatever.

Comment: You code as a return type of void. Its not going to return any value in context of ajax

Comment: Have you tried it? I have, I do this every day and it works fine. When you call the page using ajax the Page_Load event is run. This sets up the Response object and will return the plain text "Hello". You shouldn't vote down answers you don't understand and have not tried for yourself.

Comment: Your page posts back when you're doing your call and it's just the page load that's writing the text. I'd imagine that when you first initialize the page you're writing out the text as well. This is not sending back a response to the AJAX method calling it.

Comment: That is exactly right and exactly the point. You only call this page from an ajax call. I keep these pages in a folder named 'ajax' for just that reason. It's the loading of the page that writes the response. In this case it simply answers 'Hello'. It can take POST variables or Querystring variables and do database queries and sorting. Whatever you can do with any other page. Then you can format the response in any way you wish. and by setting the ContentType return any type of document to your ajax call.

Comment: yes. is realy aspx. i Know the option to write the code in another page that cleaned from HTML. but is very uncomftrable to do second page evrey time. thanks anywhys.

Comment: @regerory,  This DOES send a response to the AJAX method calling it. All an AJAX call does is make an http call to a web page and get back the response without reloading the current page. This is a webpage and it sends a response. Give it a try yourself and see if it works. This works much better for me. I can build an entire library of ajax methods that can be reused by any page in my website or any other. You can build your own REST API.

Comment: @GreggDuncan: I did not vote you down if even though the context of what is being is asked is different than what you posted.